# Init DB in the slow_log table

Tags: mysql, database

I have been doing performance tuning to one of my twitter app and I see "Init DB" in the slow_log table in mysql 5.1.

Can someone please tell me what does that mean.

Answer (score 1):

Init DB occurs when selecting a database. In PHP it would be `mysql_select_db("dbname")`

Typically, this should not show up in a slow query log, however, if `long_query_time` is set to 0, the slow query log will log all queries much like the general log.